# Increasing Answer Feedback

Tags: discussion, answers

I've noticed several questions with only one answer and no feedback (requester not accepting the answer and no upvotes) which seems to still leave the question unresolved since users have no idea if this is accurate or not.

I'm new to SE and I understand this is a beta, but is this just because of site attendance? Or is the breadth of EngrSE too large to reliably have multiple knowledgable people for answering? Is there ways when I answer or see other peoples answers to help get answers verified/accepted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't uncommon on SE. Some users ask a question without registering an account and don't care to participate in the site after they've asked their question. Some questions are so straightforward that users don't really care to add more answers after the first but also don't find the Q&A valuable enough to bother voting on.

Ultimately it often comes down to views. The more people visit a page, the more votes and comments will be left on its content. Some content is, to be blunt, neither useful nor interesting to the vast majority of people besides the person asking the question.

So if you see a question like this with only a couple dozen views, you can be pretty confident that the lack of participation stems from a lack of interest more than anything else. If you want to help draw attention to a question, you can [share a link to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/63684/254929), either internally (i.e., in one of our [chat rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)) or on any other site/platform of your choosing.

If you want to encourage a specific user who has *already* interacted with the Q&A to follow up, you can comment on one of their questions or answers or [ping them in a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/254929) on any post they've edited or commented on themselves.